# Python code to refresh the connection in individual excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, win32com, vba

I am a beginner in  python. I have written few DBQ statements in excel to fetch 
result in excel which should be refreshed whenever the excel is opened. Have given the correct setting in connection properties.

```
Below is my python code for refreshall:- 

import win32com.client  
import time
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.workbooks.open("D:\\Excel sheets\\Test_consolidation.xlsx")
xl.Visible = True
time.sleep(10)
wb.Refreshall()
```

I have 3 sheets in the excel file, which has 3 different connections. I want to refresh one after the other.

Can someone help me with the python code to refresh the connections individually ? I would be really grateful for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh? Do you mean the files are updated frequently?

Comment: Yes it is updated when the excel is opened manually. So i need some code in python which can do a refresh according to the sheets in the excel file.

Answer (score 3):

So if you want to refresh all of them but one after the other, instead of `wb.Refreshall()`, the command would be:

```
for conn in wb.connections:
    conn.Refresh()
```

If you want to link (in a dictionary for example) a connection to a sheet:

```
dict_conn_sheet = {} # create a new dict
for conn in wb.connections: # iterate over each connection in your excel file
    name_conn = conn.Name # get the name of the connection
    sheet_conn = conn.Ranges(1).Parent.Name # get the name of the sheet linked to this connection
    # add a key (the name of the sheet) and the value (the name of the connection) into the dictionary
    dict_conn_sheet[sheet_conn] = name_conn
```

Note: if one sheet has more than one connection, this is not a good way.

Then, if you want to update only one connection on a specific sheet (in my example it is called Sheet1):

```
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
# refresh the connection linked to the sheet_name 
# if existing in the dictionnary dict_conn_sheet
wb.connections(dict_conn_sheet[sheet_name]).Refresh()
```

Finally, if you know directly the name of the connection you want to update (let's say connection_Raj), just enter:

```
name_conn = 'connection_Raj'
wb.connections(name_conn).Refresh()
```

I hope it's clear even if it does not answer exactly to your question as I'm not sure I understood what you want to do.